# Cropping a UIWebView in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, uiwebview

I have a UIWebView, but don't want to display anything at the top of the page, down to about 50 pixels. I need a way to crop the UIWebView so that users cannot see what is above that 50 pixel margin. How can I go about doing this effectivly?

Comment: Simply place a view with white or black background color at the top of the webview and give its height as 50.

Comment: but when user drags below,he can see

Comment: he can see only untill he  drags , when he releases drag it will not visible

Comment: @hardikhadwani Thanks for the reply, but is there any way to do it so the user cannot see above, even if he drags?

Comment: UIWebView is a subclass of [UIScrollView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiscrollview_class/index.html).. update the content offset should solve your problem

Comment: @ShamsAhmed Thanks, but how can I do this? I found how to do it with UIScrollView, but my searches for UIWebView have turned up dry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UIWebview contains a UIScrollView which is used to display HTML content. Changing the conent offfset allow to change the page view... see example of google

```
/**
 *  basic webview boilerpoint
 */
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,
                                                                 0,
                                                                 CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame),
                                                                 CGRectGetHeight(self.view.frame))];
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://google.co.uk"]]];
[self.view addSubview:webView];

/**
 *  disable bounces so users cannot scroll beyond content & set top offset by 100 to hide parts of website
 */
webView.scrollView.bounces = NO;
webView.scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-100, 0, 0, 0);
```